# How to use API response messages in Angular 8 i18n?

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-i18n

I am in need to use translations for API responses (especially error messages)

Ex:

```
1) User name invalid for test@test.com
2) Password is incorrect for test@test.com
3) Login Success for test@test.com
```

I used i18n select for this purpose. My sample code is below:

```
<span i18n="@@common_error">{respError, select, User name invalid for {User name invalid for} Password is incorrect for { Password is incorrect for}}</span>
```

**respError** - is a variable which holds backend response

Here I am parsing the string and then comparing using i18n select which is working fine. But I am in need to add the dynamic email in the message. I tried to add like this

`{User name invalid for {Email}}`, but no luck.

Is there any other way to use variables inside {} - braces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is one example from the documatation that might help](https://angular.io/guide/i18n#pluralization):

```
<span i18n>Updated {minutes, plural, =0 {just now} =1 {one minute ago} other {{{minutes}} minutes ago}}</span>
```

From the above example, it looks like you can try to use double curly brackets instead of single:

```
{User name invalid for {{Email}}}
```